# how to fix Permission denied on directory in unix?

Tags: shell, unix, permissions, ksh

I have a ksh file which will download a zip file from the internet in the `/tmp` directory with name `f.zip`

Why do I get Permission denied?

```
$ ./downloadbcfi
Current name is /download.files.R1201BHtm.zip
/tmp/f.zip: Permissin denied
```

When I look at the permission on the `/tmp` directory everything is ok as below:
[image]

Comment: It could be because /tmp/f.zip already exists.

Comment: tried to run script as root?

Comment: Is the shell really spelling "permission" wrong, or is this not an actual copy and paste?

Comment: You are right /tmp/f.zip already exists and i have not permission to write to it. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use this command in command line tool**

```
chmod 0777 /tmp/f.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have ran your script as root and now as normal user. Then you may not have permission to read/write `f.zip`